# DKIM on aliased domains with rspamd and postfix

Tags: postfix, dkim, rspamd

I'm having trouble DKIM signing my outgoing emails when they're sent from an alias domain. That is, when I'm authenticated with `user@domain1.com` sending as `user@domain1.com` or `somebodyelse@domain1.com` my emails are correctly DKIM-signed, but if I send as `doejohn@domain2.com` the signature is **NOT** added to the mail header. I'm using postfix and rspamd, here are the relevant files:

**Postfix**

*main.cf*

```
(initial boilerplate omitted for brevity)

virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-mailbox-users.cf
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332
milter_protocol = 6
milter_mail_macros = i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
```

*master.cf*

```
(default configs omitted for brevity)

submission inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-email2email.cf
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

**rspamd**

*local.d/dkim_signing.conf*

```
path = "/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/$domain.$selector.key";
selector_map = "/etc/rspamd/dkim_selectors.map";
```

Permissions at dkim selectors path are `r-x------` for files and `r-xr-x---` for folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DKIM signing module's [Principles of operation](https://rspamd.com/doc/modules/dkim_signing.html#principles-of-operation):

> The DKIM signing module chooses signing domains and selectors
>   according to a predefined policy which can be modified with various
>   settings. Description of this default policy follows: - -
>
> - If authenticated user is present, this should be suffixed with @domain where domain is what’s seen is envelope/header From address

The secondary domain doesn't match the domain of the authenticated user. To alter this default behaviour, your [`dkim_signing.conf`](https://rspamd.com/doc/modules/dkim_signing.html#configuration) should have:

```
allow_username_mismatch = true;
```

.